# Can I watch Digimon Tri without seeing Digimon Adventure 02?

Tags: digimon, digimon-tri

When I was young, approximately 1998–2001, I watched the original Digimon Adventure. I also later (approximately 2003) watched Digimon Tamers, but I never did watch more than a few episodes of Digimon Adventure 02.

For nostalgia's sake, I'm interested in Digimon Tri, but I have no interest right now in going back to watch Digimon Adventure 02, since it's really long and only available as an unfaithful dub. I know basically who the characters are, but I don't know any of the main plot arcs. Will I be able to understand Digimon Tri without this knowledge?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but it seems Tri was written in mind to appeal to the nostalgia of solely 01, and perhaps subtly retcon out 02 partially; at least, that's how I see it. So far at least I don't believe any of the 2nd generation digidestined has really made an appearance.

Comment: The 2nd gen Digi-destined appeared very briefly in momentary flashbacks  at the beginning of the first Tri movie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the first Digimon Tri movie, you would be able to understand everything that goes on if you had only seen the very first season of Digimon Adventures, except for a couple momentary flashbacks involving vague glimpses of the Digimon Adventure 02 Digi-destined, but those flashbacks still make no sense for someone who has seen Digimon Adventure 02 anyways due to how vaguely they were shown.

Update from the second movie:

> You will need to know a little about the conflicts that happens in Digimon Adventure 02 as we see Ken Ichijouji appear, in the present day, towards the end of the second movie as the Digimon Emperor, which is quite contradictory if you have seen enough episodes of Digimon Adventures 02. Strangely however, he never speaks. The reason why he doesn't speak, or why he is even the Digimon Emperor again, is still a mystery until the third movie is released